# Read PDF File contents in VB

Tags: vb.net, pdf

Is there any way I can read the contents of PDF file in Visual Basic 2010 ?
Is there any ActiveX Control available for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use itext

[home page](http://itextpdf.com/)

[VB sample code](http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/en/examplesvb.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try ABC PDF Component http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm